# DiscordPy, Undefined Variable Channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I have some problems with discord.py i want to send jpeg file with discord.py but it gives me error.

> message": "Undefined variable 'channel'

```
 import discord

 if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
    await channel.send('Hello', file=discord.File('fff1.jpeg', spoiler=False))
```

Comment: You need to set `channel` (or the variable name you wish to call it with) a statement like - `channel = client.get_channel(<your channel id>)`. You didn't post your code with how you handle instantiating  `discord.Client()`, handling `on_ready()` and where you are sending the message.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined channel. As such, Python doesn't know where you're trying to send your message. 
If you have the message already, you can use message.channel instead of channel. to send it in the same channel it came from.

Additionally, if you're just using commands, you might find it easier to try using the [commands class](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=command#command) from discord.ext.